# How to cancel an upload or download

Tags: box-api

I have a UI that allows the user to cancel file upload/download operations, but I cannot find a way to tell Box to cancel.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but cdemiris99 provided a potential answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll want to handle client-side.

The easiest approach is probably to kill the HTTP connection associated with the upload or download and clean up any associated resources when the user cancels the operation in your UI. (How you do that specifically will vary by programming language, obviously)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm use the Box iOS SDK.  I'm not able to figure out how to do it using the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way to do this.
Use **[Box registerObserverForUploadQueue]** before calling an upload method, 
and implement the BoxObserver method **uploadDidRegisterForItem:(UploadID *)uploadID**

Then you can record the uploadID associated with the upload and cancel with that.